# how to test if json data got to a server ios

Tags: ios, json

Im trying to send some json data to a http server in my ios app, but I dont know **how to verify if data got there**... For testing Im using http://www.jsontest.com/.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://validate.jsontest.com"];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setHTTPBody:createJson()];      //createJson() is my function which pass json data
                                              encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[connection start];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://validate.jsontest.com"]]; //by this I want to open json site in browser and see if data come. - but something different should be here I guess
```

So... How should I change my code to see data from createJson() in browser? Are there any mistakes in code so data arent even sent to a server?
Thank you for any help.

Comment: Use AFNetworking. Far more Simple and Easy to intergrate.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using AFNetworking

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager GET:@"http://example.com/resources.json" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

That you have 2 blocks one runs on success & other on failure.

This is the link on Github
https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking